# What could I be doing wrong to get this result from Azure AutoML timeseries forecasting?

Tags: azure, time-series, forecasting, automl

I'm experimenting with Azure AutoML for timeseries forecasting.  I have a simple two column training dataset with two years of data at hourly intervals. Column 1 is Date/Time Column 2 is the variable I want to predict.  I've done several runs of Azure AutoML and it seems to complete successfully. However, when I do a forecast and graph it something is obviously wrong.  It looks like the forecast is being quantised somehow. The graph below is for the 7 days after the training set. Blue is actual and red is the forecast. This is obviously not right.

[image]

Here is my configuration for the training (python):

```
lags = [1,24,168]
forecast_horizon = 7 * 24 # 7 days of hourly data
forecasting_parameters = ForecastingParameters(
    time_column_name="DateTime",
    forecast_horizon=forecast_horizon,
    target_lags=lags,
    country_or_region_for_holidays='NZ',
    freq='H',
    use_stl='season',
    seasonality='auto'
)
automl_config = AutoMLConfig(task='forecasting',
                             debug_log='automl_forecasting_function.log',
                             primary_metric='normalized_root_mean_squared_error',
                             experiment_timeout_hours=1,
                             experiment_exit_score=0.05, 
                             enable_early_stopping=True,
                             training_data=train_df,
                             compute_target=compute,
                             n_cross_validations=10,
                             verbosity = logging.INFO,
                             max_concurrent_iterations=19,
                             max_cores_per_iteration=19,
                             label_column_name="Output",
                             forecasting_parameters=forecasting_parameters,
                             featurization="auto",
                             enable_dnn=False)
```

The best model from the run is a VotingEnsemble:

```
ForecastingPipelineWrapper(pipeline=Pipeline(
  memory=None,
  steps=[('timeseriestransformer',
  TimeSeriesTransformer(
    featurization_config=None,
    pipeline_type=<TimeSeriesPipelineType.FULL: 1>)),
  ('prefittedsoftvotingregressor',
  PreFittedSoftVotingRegressor(estimators=[('7',
  Pipeline(memory=None,
  steps=[('minmaxscaler',
  MinMaxScaler(copy=True,
  feature_range=(0,
  1))...
  DecisionTreeRegressor(ccp_alpha=0.0,
  criterion='mse',
  max_depth=None,
  max_features=0.5,
  max_leaf_nodes=None,
  min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
  min_impurity_split=None,
  min_samples_leaf=0.00218714609400816,
  min_samples_split=0.00630957344480193,
  min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
  presort='deprecated',
  random_state=None,
  splitter='best'))],
  verbose=False))],
  weights=[0.5,
  0.5]))],
  verbose=False),
  stddev=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I was not doing anything fundamentally wrong.  I turned off early stopping and let it run for two hours and got this...
[image]